# What are some arguments given by Advaitins against Dvaita philosophy of Madhvacharya

Tags: vedas, upanishads, madhvacharya

What is refutation of Tattvada philosophy of Madhvacharya?

Comment: Extremely broad question. It would be better to be specific and choose one topic. The whole refutation of it would require a book

Comment: Yes, if you can tell me such a book where there is whole refutation. The specific question will be that how the soul and the Brahman are one.